# Restriction of regular measures

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

I'm studying Measure theory at university. For practising with some exercises, I found some available notes on the web. While reading chapter about Borel measures, the following definitions are given:

1. A Borel measure $\mu$ on the topological space $X$ is a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra;
2. A Borel measure $\mu$ on the topological space $X$ is called regular if, for each Borel set $E$ in $X$
   $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(U) | U \text{ open}\supseteq E \}$,

   $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K)|K\text{ compact}\subseteq E\}$

Given this context, at the end of the chapter, I found the following exercise I cannot solve:

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite regular Borel measure on the topological space $X$ and $Y$ be a Borel subset of $X$. Prove that the restriction $\mu_Y$ is a regular Borel measure on $X$.
Here $\mu_Y$ is a measure defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ such that $\mu_Y(E):=\mu(E\cap Y)$ for each set $E$ in the $\sigma$-algebra.

I think a good strategy can be to solve the exercise for Borel sets $E$ such that  $\mu(E)<\infty$, and then to exploit the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ to achieve the general result.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Is $\mu$ a regular measure? I mean, otherwise when $Y=X$ the claim doesn't look true.

Comment: Yes @Keen-ameteur, I formulated the problem in a wrong way, sorry about that. Now it should be correct.